# I wanted to setup a cron job inside my module but my cron job is simply not executing

Tags: php, magento, cron

I wanted to setup a cron job inside my module but my cron job is simply not executing.

**app/code/local/Winback/Email/etc/config.xml**

```
           <?xml version="1.0"?>
           <config>

               <modules>
                   <Winback_Email>
                       <version>0.1.30</version>
                   </Winback_Email>
               </modules>

               <global>
                   <models>
                       <Winback_Email>
                           <class>Winback_Email_Model</class>
                       </Winback_Email>                         
                   </models>
               </global>

              <crontab>
                   <jobs>
                       <Winback_Email>
                           <schedule>
                               <cron_expr>*/1 * * * *</cron_expr>
                           </schedule>
                           <run>
                               <model>email/observer::setlog</model>
                           </run>
                       </Winback_Email>
                   </jobs>
               </crontab>
           </config> 

           **app/code/local/Winback/Email/Model/Observer.php**

           <?php


           class Winback_Email_Model_Observer extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
           {
               public function setlog($observer)

               {

                    Mage::log('changed log by cron', null, 'mylogfile.log');


                     return $observer;

               }
           }
```

I have installed a Cron Scheduler Module, which shows me error as exception `Mage_Core_Exception` with message

```
'Invalid callback: email/observer::setlog does not exist' in /home/leosatyen/webapps/AbandonCart/app/Mage.php:595
```

Comment: vague guess... case sensitivity? `'Email' != 'email'`

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```html
<run>
    <model>Winback_Email/observer::setlog</model>
</run>
```

Because your model group name is not email, but Winback_Email.